# Difference between Entry Criteria and Entry Data

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can you explain the different steps of the Salesforce Entry Source in Journey Builder. I cannot find information about it

The steps are:

- Entry Criteria
- Filter Criteria
- Entry Data

What´s the difference between Entry Criteria and Entry Data?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Entry Criteria** is used to define rules for records that should enter journey - for example you can define that only Contacts with Sex equal to Male should enter your journey.

**Entry Data** is where you select what data you want to pull to journey (Entry Event Data). Here you define what fields you want to pull from Sales/Service Cloud objects. Lets say you want to use Contact First Name in your messages. You can add that field in Entry Data to make it usable inside a journey in either decision spilts or for message personalization purposes.